# Micronaut Declarative Client Streaming and error handling

Tags: micronaut, rx-java3, micronaut-client

I have a client that consumes an input stream from a service, like this:

```
@Client(value = 'http://localhost:8080/')
interface StreamClient {

    @Get(uri = '/data', processes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Header("Accept: application/octet-stream")
    Flowable<byte[]> retrieveFile()
}
```

and when using it like this (Groovy):

```
void getContent(OutputStream outputStream) {
    client.retrieveFile().blockingSubscribe({ byte[] bytes ->
        outputStream.write(bytes)
    }, { Throwable error ->
        error.printStackTrace()
    })
}
```

it retrieves the stream just fine without reading the entire `byte[]` array into memory (exactly as I want it), but if the endpoint returns a 404, I just get an empty byte array, not an error as I would expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the question I'm using RxJava3 but if Reactor framework has a viable solution I have no problem switching.

Answer (score 0):

The Micronaut http client returns the declared return type (in your case `byte[]`) for status 2xx and 404. In the case of 404 you usually get `null` for objects and in your case with a primitive array it seems to be an empty array.

In order to get more control I recommend to return an `HttpResponse<byte[]>`. With this type you get access to the http status code.

Further readings about [error responses](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#lowLevelClientError) and Micronaut http client.

> If an HTTP response is returned with a code of 400 or higher, an HttpClientResponseException is created. The exception contains the original response. How that exception gets thrown depends on the return type of the method.
> For blocking clients, the exception is thrown and should be caught and
> handled by the caller. For reactive clients, the exception is passed
> through the publisher as an error.

Comment: thanks, but I need it to be reactive, as I'm potentially streaming +1GB files from the endpoint I'm calling. Using `HttpReponse<byte[]>` I suspect will stream the entire content to memory, instead of in chunks?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I haven't tried yet. But maybe you could work with StreamedFile (https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#transfers)?